# Razor views in ASP.NET Webforms application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to convert my Asp.net Webforms application into an Asp.net MVC one. I wanted to know if i could have Razor views(*.cshtml) and Aspx views(*.aspx) coexist in the same application.If yes,then how?If no,then is it ok if i use MVC with aspx pages?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have razor views and aspx views in the same project. Check out the following links, they will guide you in the right direction.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/29/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: This article refers to aspx views in asp.net mvc project,which does support 2 views..But my project is asp.net webforms project.Can a webforms project support cshtml files?

Comment: You are probably looking for "Webmatrix". Check out the link here. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/162/Using-Web-Pages-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-Web-Forms